# Ruby rb_define_method - invalid conversion

Tags: c++, ruby, qt, type-conversion

I embed Ruby in QT app and try to create class and add him new method

```
VALUE Base = rb_define_class("Base", NULL);
VALUE Base_Initialize(VALUE self);
rb_define_method(Base, "initialize", Base_Initialize, 0);
```

But i get error while compile

```
invalid conversion from 'VALUE (*)(VALUE) {aka long unsigned int (*)(long unsigned int)}' to 'VALUE (*)(...) {aka long unsigned int (*)(...)}' [-fpermissive]
```

In c extension worked fine.

Comment: Perhaps `Base_Initialize` needs to be `extern "C"`?

Comment: `extern "C"`, as i know, needed in c++ extension, not embeded ruby. By the way, i tried this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add `reinterpret_cast< VALUE ( * ) ( ... ) >(BaseItem_Initialize)` and it`s worked.

```
VALUE Base = rb_define_class("Base", NULL);
VALUE Base_Initialize(VALUE self);
rb_define_method(Base, "initialize", reinterpret_cast< VALUE ( * ) ( ... ) >(BaseItem_Initialize), 0);
```